# vuejs watch multidimensional array with change info

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an Array "contracts" in which there are arrays of each contract information.
On the editing page I'd like to have the Info which contract was edited.

```js
new Vue({
data(): {
  return {
    contracts: [
      {name:"a",changed:false},{name:"b",changed:false}
    ]
  }
},
watch: {
  contracts: {
    handler: function(val) {
           this.contracts[x].changed=true;
    },
    deep=true
  }
}
});
```

I simply want to find "x", the Index of the changed Array. The number of contracts is variable so watching every single one wouldn´t work.

Comment: Sry, but there are at least typos in your sample code. “**contrats**” and “**name=**”

Comment: Thanks for the info, i‘ve changed the code sample

Comment: I assume you are using the contracts in a `v-for`?  If so, I would make a child component to pass each array object and the index of the `v-for` to and watch it internally then `$emit` out the index and values on change.

Comment: Assumed correct  i‘ll definetly try that! Thanks!